# how to load data of current page in extjs 3.4 grid

Tags: extjs, grid

i have a EditorGridPanel which have more data and i am is 10th page of the grid i want to delete one record of this page and load the grid store with same page who can i do this ,if i  simply load the grid its come to the first page with max and offset 25 and 0. please suggest me here is my code of grid:

```
var crashEventGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
            id : 'crashEventGrid',
            store : ds,
            layout : 'fit',
            stripeRows : true,
            cm : crashEventCM(),
            sm : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect : true
            }),
            loadMask : {
                msg : 'Loading ..'
            },
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: true,
                stripeRows: false,
                emptyText : 'There are no items to show in this view.',
                showPreview:true,
                getRowClass: function(record) { 

                    return record.data.type =="ERROR" ? 'app42-x-grid3-row' : '.none'; 
                } 

            },
            bbar : new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                store : ds,
                displayInfo : true,
                pageSize : 25
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reloading store with same paging configuration you can use `Ext.data.Store` [`reload()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload) method.

You can reload your grid's store like this:

```
crashEventGrid.getStore().reload();
```